# Has a Ferengi ever worked for Section 31?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

To quote [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72001/120192) answer:

> This is similar to the situation with the Ferengi in Star Trek. Due to
>   their willingness to trade with anyone - they even trade with the
>   Dominion - and their expressed desire to maintain neutrality, it makes
>   more sense for the various powers in the Alpha Quadrant to maintain
>   Ferenginar as an independent state, rather than to destroy or conquer
>   it.

Given their willingness to trade items and information while maintaining neutrality, has a Ferengi ever worked for Section 31?

It makes sense if you think about it, you trade with targets or enemies of S31 and gather information or technology, and no one would suspect a species of comical greedy traders of espionage.

Your biggest concern would be that the target doesn't offer more Latinum to double cross you.

I'm including all canon and non-canon material (video games, books, etc..)

Comment: S31 is technically Starfleet still - so at this point, wouldn't the question be "has Nog ever worked for S31?"

Comment: @NKCampbell - Sure, but S31 can recruit who ever they want for the job, remember Sloan tried to recruit Bashir a few times.

Comment: Sloan was probably Quark and Rom's mother in disguise.

Comment: right...Bashir was in Starfleet though. S31 may indeed have tried to leverage a Ferengi. I guess the better way to ask would be, has S31 ever told a Ferengi asset the asset was working for S31?

Comment: Maybe it should be worded as "with" rather than "for"?

Comment: Captain Nog worked *with* Section 31 in the Rule 125 STO event; https://stt.wiki/wiki/Rule_125

Comment: "Your biggest concern would be that the target doesn't offer more Latinum to double cross you." To be fair that is a major concern...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Star Trek Online episode *Bait and Switch, Parts I and II.* a Section 31 Agent named [Grell](https://memory-gamma.fandom.com/wiki/Grell) appears. He's a Ferengi operative, initially working directly under Franklin Drake, then promoted above him.

[image]

<sub>Note that while [The Foundry](https://sto.gamepedia.com/The_Foundry) is a well respected fan-episode creation group, their work isn't considered canon to the main game</sub>

Comment: Nice find, *Note that while The Foundry is a well respected fan-episode creation group, their work isn't considered canon to the main game*. I'm including all non-canon material so +1 for this find.